# Page Transitions in all directions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, transition

I am very new to GreenSocks and I am still exploring all the possibilities.

What I'm looking for is a way to create something like
 http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ horizontal and vertical page slide.

What I really want to accomplish is making full page transitions  left, right, top and down with
dynamic PHP pages with navigation.
Basically, when you click on a menu in navigation the page will slide left or right or top or bottom.
I try to keep URL as they are not like in one-page anchor # thing

Is it possible to achieve something like this with JQuery or  GreenSock?
If so could someone point me in the direction of documentation and examples. I have looked around but not sure where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use ajax to load the different pages, just like you would using "#", but use push state to change the URL to "real" url's instead of using "#".

Comment: so you are saying to use fullPage.js to make transitions and with push state changing urls?

Comment: Something like that, yes. You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/.